# VBA - User-defined type not defined

Tags: windows, vba

I am trying to update an VBA module to use the `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` class. I declared my object as follows:

```
Dim MyFolderBrowser As New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
```

Running this gave me the error `User-defined type not defined`. I figured the compiler didn't know about that class so I tried going to `Tools > References` and adding `Systems_Windows_Forms`, but I'm still getting the same error. Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Do I need a reference to the library in my code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` looks like something from `.Net` to me, not VBA.

You can use `Application.FileDialog` in Access VBA.  This sample uses late binding and allows the user to select a folder from a browse dialog.

```vb
Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker As Long = 4
Dim objFileDialog As Object ' FileDialog
Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With objFileDialog 
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
```

If you prefer to use early binding, set a reference to the *Microsoft Office [version] Object Library*.  You could then declare the object like this ...

```vb
Dim objFileDialog As FileDialog
```

And you wouldn't need to define the constant, so discard this line if using early binding ...

```vb
Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker As Long = 4
```