# MSAccess - File-Open Dialog w/Many Versions of Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've implemented a file-open dialog in my local copy of a database - works as expected for me.  I added the necessary reference to "Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library".

This database has a wide range of users using many versions of Office/Access (2007 thru 2013), which I do detect and log to a variable upon opening the APP.

```
MSAccess revision numbers

Select Case SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessVer)
    Case 7: myVersion = "95"
    Case 8: myVersion = "97"
    Case 9: myVersion = "2000"
    Case 10: myVersion = "2002"
    Case 11: myVersion = "2003"
    Case 12: myVersion = "2007"
    Case 13: myVersion = "Pirated!"
    Case 14: myVersion = "2010"
    Case 15: myVersion = "2013"
    Case Else: myVersion = "Unknown"
End Select
```

How does Access accommodate the Office Object Library reference for users < Office 2013??

I already do conditionally account for 32 & 64 bit machines,  Is this a similar approach?

Any guidance??

Answer (score 3):

'How does Access accommodate the Office Object Library reference for users < Office 2013?' - not very well. Once you know the code works, I'd remove the explicit reference and use late rather than early binding. Same goes for any other Office references (e.g. to Excel)...

Comment: +1 for suggesting "late binding". @MarkPelletier - See another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15906899/2144390) for an example.