# User chosen file directory Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am currently importing a folder full of excel files into Access using the code below. I want to export macro to others, but with the hard coded path it would not work for others. But I am not sure how to change the path to accept a user input I would like to try and make something like a file explorer but not sure how.

```
Dim otable As DAO.TableDef
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strpath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' accept excel first line as headers for tables
blnHasFieldNames = True

' Path to files
strpath = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Test\"


strFile = Dir(strpath & "*.xls")

'import all files within selected folder
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
strPathFile = strpath & strFile
strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Below is what I have tried changing though I am given an error of "Method 'filedialog' of object_'Application' failed" and am not sure if I am using this incorrectly.

```
strpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

Comment: Please show us the code which fails using `Application.FileDialog`.  Here a is working example of Access VBA using [Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15906899/77335)

Comment: I created a new macro to try the link provided and I still got the error "Method 'filedialog' of object_'Application' failed"

Comment: Are you talking about an Access macro or Access VBA?

Comment: No, it's plain VBA.  I just tested it again in Access 2010, and it works without error.  Maybe if you show us your failing code, we can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I can't edit the comment for another few minutes but I made a mistake and your link does work for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can the folder selection become the path for my importing loop?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of `Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1)`, use `strpath = .SelectedItems(1) & Chr(92)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please submit your solution as an answer and accept it when the system allows.  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to HansUp for the help on solving this.

The to select a folder and upload all files within the folder is below...

```
Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker As Long = 4
Dim objfiledialog As Object
Dim otable As DAO.TableDef
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strpath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' accept excel first line as headers for tables
blnHasFieldNames = True

'select folder and set path
Set objfiledialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With objfiledialog
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show Then
 strpath = .SelectedItems(1) & Chr(92)
 End If
End With

strFile = Dir(strpath & "*.xls")

'import all files within selected folder
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
strPathFile = strpath & strFile
strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: Looks good, Rukgo.  I suggest you check to ensure `Len(strpath) > 0` so that you don't attempt the rest of the code when user clicks "Cancel" in the `FileDialog`.